# Sending EOF to NSTask via NSPipe or NSFileHandle

Tags: cocoa, stdin, eof, nstask, nspipe

I have an NSTask which processes arguments passed from stdin.
The arguments are passed via `NSFileHandle`.

It's working fine, but our command line tool reads input from stdin until it receives the EOF symbol (by pressing Ctrl+C).

I don't think I can add the EOF symbol to an ASCII string, so what would be the options?
Any feedback appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ctrl-c isn't EOF; it's SIGINT (interrupt). Moreover, EOF isn't a character; it's the End Of File. So, to “send EOF”, you just end the file.

Comment: @PeterHosey Technically, there is indeed a EOF character defined by ASCII, and it's been in use. But sending that char into the file won't help on a Mac, admittedly.

Comment: Ah yes, the End of Transmission character—also known as Ctrl-D. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `closeFile` on the writing end of the pipe signals the EOF condition:

```
NSPipe *inPipe = [NSPipe new];
[task setStandardInput:inPipe];

[[inPipe fileHandleForWriting] writeData:...];
// ...
[[inPipe fileHandleForWriting] closeFile];
```